# Screw and washer should go through flat area or curved?

Tags: screws, hole, washer, frame

I have a screw with a washer. Which one of the two sides should it go through (ie which side the washer should be "in contact with"), the flat or the curved one? The structure is symmetrical so it can go either way. The other side of the frame (opposite to where the washer will be) is going to be mounted to a flat surface. Basically the screw goes through the hole of the metal frame and screws on the flat surface on the other side. If someone also knows the reason why one is more suitable than the other it would be great.

[image: flat]
[image: curved]
[image: screw]

Comment: won't the washer defeat the purpose of the indentation is used on that side - keeping it from sitting flat?

Comment: How about a picture of the screw.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. That's what I thought. Plus the inner angle of the other side should make sure there are no deformities due to manufacturing when sitting on a flat surface. But I am no expert, hence asking. :)

Comment: @JACK attached. It's a flat head hex screw. Goes through the hole and screws on a plate on the other side of the metal frame where it will be attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The depression you're asking about appears to be simply sloppy manufacturing to me. It doesn't seem like an intentional countersink. If it was you'd probably have flat-head screws instead.

1. The washer goes under the nut when working with metal, not under the screw head (unless there is no nut or it's an integrated nut).
2. The screw head should be oriented where it's accessible and gives the best appearance.

I'd put that ugly dent against the mounting surface and the screw head against a nice flat hole, personally, No matter where you put it you'll mash that tubing if you tighten too much, so go easy.